# How Cassandra Handle a select query?

Tags: cassandra, garbage-collection, partitioning

I'm working on designing Cassandra column family.

I met with a situation of higher GC while SELECTing, after loading a higher density of data. That is, amount of data in a partition increased. Also for low density data, it works fine.

I want to know how Cassandra does the SELECT query (with both partition and cluster key specified)?

Is the whole set of data in a partition is loaded into memory while we execute SELECT?

Will large number of partition keys affect performance?

Comment: Please add the query samples and also elaborate on what you mean by high density and low destiny. Is it querying with or without clustering key and each partition being high or low on associated clustering columns?

Comment: Table's structure is like this - PRIMARY KEY(A,B,C). Table is having few fields (p,q,r,s,t) also.  Sample query - SELECT p,q,r,s,t FROM table where A=? AND B =?;

Comment: Data density increase as more B and C entries get INSERTed.

Comment: Did you execute delete query or explicitly insert null ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam no DELETE query is executed.

Comment: How much data in a single partition ?

Comment: It might be some 2 to 4 gb. I guess that might be the issue. That why I'm asking How Cassandra does SELECT query. Will Cassandra load a full partition into memory while executing SELECT query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassandra does not load the entire partition into memory, but it does load IndexInfo objects which help Cassandra find the relevant CQL rows within the partition. These are short lived java objects which can create quite a bit of heap pressure (GC pauses) - this is a design issue that will be addressed in CASSANDRA-9754 (known as Birch, a b-tree implementation of the index data structure).

Until cassandra-4.0 is released, you should target 100MB for your max partition size, and break larger partitions into smaller pieces.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. If i increase number of partition ( partition count < 2^63), how is it going to affect Cassandra performance?  Especially read performance?

Comment: Lots of partitions is fine. You can even go above 2^63, if you have that much data (cassandra can/does handle multiple partition keys hashing to the same token just fine). 

You really only want data in a partition if you're querying it together, where cassandra can cluster the data (sorted) on disk and grab it in groups. If you're not grabbing many rows from a partition, break it up.

Also, if you have multiple partitions, you can issue multiple asynchronous SELECT calls at one time, and more efficiently parallelize the queries.